Export messages from private telegram channel with Telegram Bot API
I am using this code to get all messages from a private Telegram channel from this topic:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel

api_id = 123456798
api_hash = "XXXXX"
session_name = "my_session"
private_channel_id = 123456789


if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()

    # Get Private Channel Messages
    messages = client.get_messages(PeerChannel(channel_id=private_channel_id))
    for message in client.iter_messages(PeerChannel(channel_id=private_channel_id)):
        print(message.sender_id, ":", message.text)

When I try to get messages with a bot token I get this error:
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetHistoryRequest)

Is there another way to get messages from a private channel using a bot instead of a "real" user?
Thanks

Bots cannot get the message history, but they can listen to events.
